# Compressing the dataToURL data - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there anyway the data within the dataToURL can be compressed? I don't mean the image quality, just the string that the dataToURL generates. It's just that when I append the string to a JavaScript list, it takes about a second on an iPad. I would like to compress the string, as well as uncompressing it, so that it takes less time on an iPad. In case you are unsure as to what I would like compressed, here is the following:

```
tempStoreRecords.push(tempCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

tempStoreRecords is the list that stores the canvas through the toDataURL and tempCanvas is the HTML5 canvas I wish to compress through the toDataURL.

Comment: What is this string used for? You'd probably be better saving either the canvas directly, or at least a blob output (`canvas.toBlob(b=>tempStoreRecords.push(b))`)

Comment: It is used to save each one as an image through PHP. The code records a screenshot per 400 or 1200 milliseconds for the first 5 screenshots to show where users start to colour in the canvas at. However, the larger the canvas, the more gaps that appear while the user is colouring in due to the application storing the current state of the canvas for each 400 or 1200 milliseconds. I came up with an solution to solve this by copying the canvas to a new canvas and then scaling it down before storing the string. It seems like old iPads can't handle saving canvases that have a large width and height.